# shader heightmap translation following camera in libgdx on an tiledmap

Tags: opengl, libgdx, glsl, shader, tile

I am trying to create a nice water distortion effect using shader on a 2D game based on libgdx using heightmap.

At first, I render the whole scene to a FBO

[image: first rendering with no effects]

then I apply the distortion effect to the rendered FBO and use a mask to determine the waterfall location.
Before applying the mask:

[image: before the mask]

[image]

To achieve the effect, I translate the Y coordinate of the heightmap in the shader based on time and I loop in it using `fract(heighmapCoord)`.

The problem is that when the camera move to follow the player, the heighmap stay static on the X axis.
I decided to translate the `heightmapCoord` based on the `camera.position` and the `fract()` function. The heighmap seems to follow the camera but with less speed, causing the effect to slide inside the waterfall mask.

It seems that there is a projection problem. Also, I am not sure if this is the good way to create this kind of effect.

How can I make the heightmap following exactly the camera move?

EDIT:

I only use a fragment shader, the vertex one is the passthrought shader:

```
void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position =  u_projTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You have to translate the coordinate from screen to the shader as the following:

assuming the screen as a viewport of 15 * 10 tiles (width * height), you will need to translate the heighmap texture coord as

```
texCoord.x += camera.x / viewPortTileWidth;  // 15
texCoord.y += camera.y / viewPortTileHeight; // 10
```

then the heighmap will not slide anymore as the player is moving.